# jquery .index()

Tags: jquery, css, indexing

the jquery index() seems not recognize one of the element, always say "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" here is my code.. mnumber is the one causing problems.i need number and mnumber to be able to track use mouse, and give them correct value base on which box they hover to.

```
$(".module-details-lesson-container").hover(function () {
    var number = $(".module-details-lesson-container").index(this) - 9;
    var mnumber = $(".module-container").index(this);
    jQuery.each(modules[1][number], function (index, value) {
        $(".module-details-words-learned-body").eq(1).append("<div class='module-details-word'>" + value + '</div>');
    });
}, function () {
    $(".module-details-word").remove();
});
```

css file

```
<div class="module-container">
<div class="module-tab  envelope-heading white-font"></div>
<div class="module-body">


            <div class="module-details-lesson-container"></div>
            <div class="module-details-lesson-container"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="module-details-words-learned">
            <div class="module-details-words-learned-body ">
                <div class="module-details-word"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it have to be `$(this)` instead of `this` everywhere it mentioned

Comment: what should i use if i want to get the correct index number of class .module-container, it is the parent container of .module-details-lesson-container, and i have 10 module-container on this page

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you might be misusing the keyword `this`. To access the proper object in the scope that you want, you need to replace it with $(this) inside your delegate functions:

```
$(".module-details-lesson-container").hover(function(){
        // Changed this to $(this) below
        var number = $(".module-details-lesson-container").index($(this))-9;
        var mnumber = $(".module-container").index($(this));

        jQuery.each(modules[1][number], function(index,value){
            $(".module-details-words-learned-body").eq(1).append("<div class='module-details-word'>" + value + '</div>');
        });
    },
    function(){$(".module-details-word").remove();
});
```